# Check if a number completely divides by 4

Tags: php

I need to know if a changing number divides completely by 4. this is the code that I am currently using:

```
if ($ResultsCounter %4 != 0){
        $htmlResult .=  "</div><div class='row'>"; 
    }
```

Problem here is that if the number is greater than 0 it will always divide by 4. I need this to run if the result is a whole number... i.e. 4, 8, 12, 6...

Comment: if($ResultsCounter % 1 == 0) to see if its a whole number should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change from

```
if ($ResultsCounter %4 != 0){
```

to

```
if ($ResultsCounter %4 == 0){
```

Comment: @rehmat the OP specifically said it needs it to work for whole numbers, aka natural numbers, aka integers.

Comment: @jcaron sorry for this ;)